# How can I group the null results in this FULL OUTER JOIN with non-null responses?

Tags: join, coalesce, hive

I am looking at the overlap and non-overlap (unique values) of users-ids from two different select statements using a full join. The main differentiation being that one table will have a deal_id = 0 and the other will have any deal_id greater than or equal to one. 
I am joining the select statements on exchange_id, pub_id, and user_id but not on deal_id.

The field *incremental value* is trying to calculate users who are present in the pool deal_id >= 1 and not present in the pool of deal_id = 0 (a main reason for the full join).

Here is a simplification of the query I've typed up, it's in two select statements :

```
SET
hive.auto.convert.join = TRUE
;

SELECT
    First.deal_id
    ,COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id ) as exchange_id
    ,COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id ) as pub_id
    ,COUNT (DISTINCT(case when Second.user_id is null then First.user_id else null END)) AS Incremental
    ,SUM (First.imps) AS First_imps
    ,SUM (Second.imps) AS Second_imps
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                a.deal_id
                ,a.exchange_id
                ,a.pub_id
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                logs a 
            WHERE
                a.deal_id >= 1
            AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
        ) First 
        FULL JOIN (
            SELECT
                a.exchange_id
                ,a.pub_id
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                logs a
            WHERE
            a.deal_id = 0
            AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
        ) Second
        ON (
            First.exchange_id = Second.exchange_id
            AND First.pub_id = Second.pub_id
            AND First.user_id = Second.user_id
        )
        GROUP BY
        First.deal_id
        ,COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id )
        ,COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id )
;
```

Here are the results I am seeing:

```
DEAL_ID    EXCHANGE_ID    PUB_ID    INCREMENTAL    FIRST_IMPS    SECOND_IMPS
/N         4              1780      0              0             15
/N         4              1560      0              0             32
3389       4              1780      2              7             6
1534       4              1560      4              9             8
```

And here is what I would like to see:

```
DEAL_ID    EXCHANGE_ID    PUB_ID    INCREMENTAL    FIRST_IMPS    SECOND_IMPS
3389       4              1780      2              7             21
1534       4              1560      4              9             40
```

Where the results with a null deal id match up to the results with a non-null deal id based on exchange_id and pub_id.

What can I do?

Similar to this [problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15312/why-is-this-full-outer-join-not-working) but this solution isn't working for this problem.

Note: I've posted this question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742112/why-does-a-full-join-on-all-but-one-field-return-null-values-on-that-field) but thought I might try dba instead

Edit: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e0ff/1/0) is a sqlfiddle that replicates the problem, note that it's using PostgreSQL while I'm using hql

Comment: Is the `(exchange_id, pub_id, user_id)` unique in each table? (i.e. no 2 rows with same exchange_id, pub_id, and user_id in a table?)

Comment: And do you have `deal_id` in the `GROUP BY` list? It doesn't seem like a valid query otherwise. Plus I don't see how can have `GROUP BY exchange_id, pub_id` and get multiple rows with these 2 columns identical.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes on both accounts, `(exchange_id, pub_id, user_id)` is unique in each table and the `deal_id` is in the `GROUP BY`, have corrected the query above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(deal_id, exchange_id, pub_id)` above. Rewriting to be clear:

Comment: OK, looks good but we have this problem now (in order to answer the real question): Say we have 2 rows, with `(deal_id, exchange_id, pub_id)`: `(3389, 4, 1780)` and `(3390, 4, 1780)` (which I think should be coming from the `First` table) and another (1) row with `(NULL, 4, 1780)` which should be coming from the `Second` table. Now the problem is: when we add up the group with `(exchange_id, pub_id) = (4, 1780)`, the summations are not a problem. But which `deal_id` to show in the result? `3389` or `3390`? (because we can only show one)

Comment: I sort of see what you're saying, it doesn't aggregate because the conditions aren't clear enough. In my head I was hoping for what usually happens in a [left] or [right] join where matches can happen on more than one item
Is there a manipulation that we can do so that it's shown on more than one `deal_id` or is something inherently wrong with the query?

Comment: I'm asking what you want to happen - in the specific case I described above. So I can answer.

Comment: I would like the sums of `(exchange_id, pub_id)` to be added to both `deal_id`s `3389` and `3390`

Comment: Last question: in the rows with `deal_id = 0`, is the `user_id` null? It would be helpful if you added a small sample of rows from the original table. Oh, you have a fiddle, let me check. SQLfidle seems uncoopertive at the moment. Can you paste the sample to [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk)  ?

Comment: No the `user_id` shouldn't be null

Comment: actually heres a more [accurate](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1c4a96a47d9e6d6ed38917490f7f4e57) one, with an overlapping user_id so that you can see the incremental function

Comment: Would that solve your issue?: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=02c256ea506984cd82d7a50f093ef1f4

Comment: Not quite, because We are now missing the Sum of Second_imps, and incremental isn't simply the distinct users from the First table, it's the distinct users from the first table that don't exist in the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this solution works. It's not very elegant and I'm worried over scale(does it run the subquery twice or once) but it works. Here is the [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ee8ce0d85ccad755775ed2b0ca590908)

```
WITH subquery as
       ( 
SELECT
    First.deal_id
    ,COALESCE( First.exchange, Second.exchange ) as exchange_id
    ,COALESCE( First.publisher, Second.publisher ) as pub_id
    ,COUNT (DISTINCT(case when Second.user_id is null then First.user_id else null END)) AS Incremental
    ,SUM (First.imps) AS First_imps
    ,SUM (Second.imps) AS Second_imps
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                a.deal_id
                ,a.exchange
                ,a.publisher
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                T1 a 
            WHERE
                a.deal_id >= 1
        ) First 
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                a.exchange
                ,a.publisher
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                T1 a
            WHERE
            a.deal_id = 0
        ) Second
        ON (
            First.exchange = Second.exchange
            AND First.publisher = Second.publisher
            AND First.user_id = Second.user_id
        )
        GROUP BY
        First.deal_id
        ,COALESCE( First.exchange, Second.exchange )
        ,COALESCE( First.publisher, Second.publisher )
        )

SELECT
deal.deal_id,
deal.exchange_id,
deal.pub_id,
sum(deal.incremental),
sum(deal.first_imps),
sum(coalesce(deal.second_imps, 0) + coalesce(oa.second_imps,0))
FROM 
subquery deal
LEFT JOIN 
subquery oa 
ON (deal.exchange_id = oa.exchange_id
AND deal.pub_id = oa.pub_id
AND oa.deal_id is null)
WHERE deal.deal_id is not null
GROUP BY
deal.deal_id,
deal.exchange_id,
deal.pub_id
;
```

Answer (score 2):

All this approach does in to make your original query a derived table then group by pub_id.

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join = TRUE;

SELECT max(DEAL_ID) as DEAL_ID
     , EXCHANGE_ID
     , PUB_ID
     , sum(INCREMENTAL) as INCREMENTAL
     , sum(FIRST_IMPS) as FIRST_IMPS
     , sum(SECOND_IMPS) as SECOND_IMPS
  FROM (

    SELECT First.deal_id
         , COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id ) as exchange_id
         , COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id ) as pub_id
         , COUNT(DISTINCT(case when Second.user_id is null then First.user_id else null END)) AS Incremental
        , SUM(First.imps) AS First_imps
        , SUM(Second.imps) AS Second_imps
    FROM (SELECT a.deal_id
               , a.exchange_id
               , a.pub_id
               , a.user_id
               , 1 AS imps
            FROM logs a 
           WHERE a.deal_id >= 1
            AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
         ) First 
FULL JOIN (SELECT a.exchange_id
                , a.pub_id
                , a.user_id
               , 1 AS imps
            FROM logs a
           WHERE a.deal_id = 0
             AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
          ) Second
      ON (   First.exchange_id = Second.exchange_id
         AND First.pub_id = Second.pub_id
         AND First.user_id = Second.user_id
         )
   GROUP BY First.deal_id
          , COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id )
          , COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id )

  ) group by pub_id, exchange_id
```

;

Comment: Actually, I've found that this eliminates some Deal_IDs that aren't null, as per @ypercubeᵀᴹ questioning above where he says `"Say we have 2 rows, with (deal_id, exchange_id, pub_id): (3389, 4, 1780) and (3390, 4, 1780) (which I think should be coming from the First table) and another (1) row with (NULL, 4, 1780) which should be coming from the Second table. Now the problem is: when we add up the group with (exchange_id, pub_id) = (4, 1780), the summations are not a problem. But which deal_id to show in the result? 3389 or 3390? (because we can only show one)"`

Comment: You are absolutely correct - this answer assigns everything to the max deal_id, even other deal_ids if they are less than the max.  I can fix the query to retain deal_ids that are less than max but I can't address the issue of assigning the null deal_ids to the proper place.